# ST_GeomFromGeoJSON strips coordinates, is it a bug?

Tags: postgis, geojson

I'm storing some geo paths in PostGIS using GeoJSON and the `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON()`-function but I just found an issue with it:

```
SELECT ST_NumPoints(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-122.023468,37.330232,0],[-122.02345,37.330233,0],[-122.02345,37.330233,0],[-122.023405,37.330236,0]]}')) = 4; -- FALSE

SELECT ST_NumPoints(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (-122.023468 37.330232 0, -122.02345 37.330233 0, -122.02345 37.330233 0, -122.023405 37.330236 0)')) = 4; -- TRUE
```

It seems to strip the two 'middle' coordinates because they are the same. And I can buy that it would do that but it doesn't do it consistently, like when I use `ST_GeomFromText()` with the same list of coordinates. It also does not strip the coordinates when using `"type": "MultiPoints"` instead, but it would be the wrong semantics.

It's a problem for me because I need the points to match a sequence of timestamps as well or data will be lost. And the reason I'm using GeoJSON is that the app server is written in Javascript so it just seems natural.

I'm running Postgres 9.4.1 and `SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version()` gives me:

```
POSTGIS="2.1.5 r13152" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" RASTER
```

Comment: If anyone is curious I've worked around it by changing doing this little hack:

`ST_LineFromMultiPoint(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"MultiPoint","coordinates":[[-122.023468,37.330232,0],[-122.02345,37.330233,0],[-122.02345,37.330233,0],[-122.023405,37.330236,0]]}'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, it's a bug. You can simplify it with:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
  ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[0,0],[1,1],[1,1],[2,2]]}'));

        st_astext
-------------------------
 LINESTRING(0 0,1 1,2 2)
```

Which should be `LINESTRING(0 0,1 1,1 1,2 2)`.

You should [file a ticket to get it fixed](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/). If you don't have a user ID, [follow these instructions](http://www.osgeo.org/osgeo_userid/).

**Update**: [postgis-2.1.6](http://postgis.net/2015/03/20/postgis-2.1.6) and later have this fix. Also affected with similar behavior were GML and KML loader functions. To remove repeated points, since 2.0 you can use `ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints`.

Comment: Posted to trac: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3061

Comment: @RobertSköld and [patched in postgis-2.1.6](http://postgis.net/2015/03/20/postgis-2.1.6) less than a month later!

Comment: I saw that, great turn around! :)